# Attempting Authentication via Azure AD B2C and Authorization via groups from AAD

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

So I followed the below examples:
Hosted Blazor Web Assembly AAD B2C: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
Azure Active Directory groups and roles : [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/azure-active-directory-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

I first implemented Hosted Blazor Web Assembly and got that working fine. Went to implement the Group and Roles parts and began to have issues.

Everything is word for word as in the examples but not sure I merged or setup the Program.cs right in the client. When attempting the call I get a "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
Authorization failed."

Unfortunately none of my breakpoints work so I figured I would reach out and see if any one has any advice.
This is built from the scaffolding for Blazor.
Here is my program.cs in my client app setup.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("<Server Project Name>", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("KeeperLife.UI.ServerAPI"));

            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {

                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://<Full path to >/API.Access ");
            });
            builder.Services.AddScoped<GraphAPIAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("GraphAPI",
                client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com"))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<GraphAPIAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState,
                CustomUserAccount>(options =>
                    {
                        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd",
                            options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                        //Originally this was "..." but it seemed to break base config so i added the same as above and that worked but then tested with it commented out and it still worked so left it commented out.
                        //options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://<Url to full API PAth>/API.Access");

                        options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalScopesToConsent.Add(
                            "https://graph.microsoft.com/Directory.Read.All");
                    })
                    .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount,
                        CustomUserFactory>();
            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("SiteAdmin", policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim("group", "<The Object ID of the group>"));
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your breakpoints don't work. But as far as I know, AAD B2C does not provide an Out-of-the-box RBAC functionality.

In Azure AD we can implement it by modifying the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest: `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"`. But it's not available in Azure AD B2C.

There is a workaround. Add a new claim type 'groups' into the custom policy and call the Microsoft Graph to get user's groups. Here is an [example](https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/) for your reference.

Vote this [user voice post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D) will be helpful.